# NetworkX drawn upstream / downstream from a search on Node or Node Attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

If you had the following NetworkX graph, how would you add a searchbox so you could type in search criteria "b" or "c" and either "upstream" or "downstream" and the graph would show (b,c,e or b,d,a) or (c,e or c,b,d,a)?
Could this also be extended to attributes in place of the nodes themselves if you added them? (so it would chart all nodes that have a property that matches or contains a search term and all upstream/downstream nodes?

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
g.add_edge(1,2)
g.add_edge(4,2)
g.add_edge(3,5)
g.add_edge(2,3)


nx.draw(g,with_labels=True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I'm also having trouble adding my attributes from an attributes dataframe.
How do you convert the table dataframe into attributes?

```py
import pandas as pd

attributes = {
  "Nodes": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
  "Attribute": ["AttributeA", "AttributeA", "AttributeA", "AttributeB", "AttributeB", "AttributeB"],
  "AttributeValue": ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text1", "Text2", "Text3"]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
attributes_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, attributes_df )
```